# Choosing signs in inverse trigonometric composing

Tags: trigonometry

I understood why he chose the positive square root in the sin but why the tan is also positive ? Isn't the tan positive and negative in this interval ?
[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment.  It said choose the + sign for the sin.  For the tan, the sign depends on the sign of x.  For negative x where the angle would be in the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ the tan would be negative.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when $-1 <x < 0$, $$\tan(\cos^{-1}(x)) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} < 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $\theta\ne\pi/2$,
$$
\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
$$
Since you have already established that $\sin\arccos x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, you can directly conclude that
$$
\tan\arccos x=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}
$$
because $\cos\arccos x=x$ by definition.

Using $\pm$ is misleading, in my opinion.